# Error in Swift JSON when receiving 'json_encode' from PHP script. Works fine without it

Tags: php, ios, json, swift

I have a Swift function for a button that when pressed writes some details into a database via PHP:

```
 @IBAction func createCommunityButtonTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    let communityName = communityNameTextField.text;
    if (communityName!.isEmpty){
        displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage: "You must name your Community");

        return;
    }else{

        func generateRandomStringWithLength(length: Int) -> String {

            var randomString = ""
            let letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"

            for _ in 1...length {
                let randomIndex  = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(letters.characters.count)))
                let a = letters.index(letters.startIndex, offsetBy: randomIndex)
                randomString +=  String(letters[a])
            }

            return randomString
        }

        let communityCode = generateRandomStringWithLength(length: 6)
        passwordTextField.text = communityCode

        let myUrl = URL(string: "http://www.quasisquest.uk/KeepScore/createCommunity.php?");

        var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!);
        request.httpMethod = "POST";

        let postString = "communityname=\(communityName!)&code=\(communityCode)&email=\(myEmail!)";

        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if (try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject]) != nil {
            }
        } 

        task.resume()

    }

}
```

The function works great apart from whenever I add this `echo json`line into the PHP script:

```
if($newresult)
{
    $returnValue["status"] = "Success";
    $returnValue["message"] = "Community is registered";
    echo json_encode($returnValue);
    return;
}
```

Then I get an error `Thread 8: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subside = 0x0)` on this line:

`if (try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject]) != nil {
                }`

And in the debug area the following details

`data   Data?   some
response    URLResponse?    0x0000618000223500
error   Error?  nil none`

I think I'm missing a line, or need to set a variable to the JSONSerialization instead of 'try!' but I'm very unsure what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning `null`. Try this

```
if($newresult)
{
 $returnValue["status"] = "Success";
 $returnValue["message"] = "Community is registered";
 return json_encode($returnValue);
}
```